# AWS ECS - how to route traffic based on client header to different service instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-ecs, multi-tenant, gateway

We moved our services to AWS ECS. We want to create different instances of those services which can differ in the:

- underlying EC2 instance size - e.g. higher CPU and RAM for bigger customers, smaller shared instances e.g. Demo clients
- a different version of the service

Ideally, we would like to use custom headers (e.g. client-id) to decide on the routing. Is this approach correct? How to achieve that? Can you share any best practices in this space? Could this be achieved using only Application Load Balancer without API Gateways? Can we have a single cluster with different EC2 instances manually attached or better to create multiple clusters e.g. demo, standard and premium?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an application load balancer to route traffic using standard or custom HTTP headers of your choosing. You can achieve this by adding listener rules that uses a condition that checks HTTP headers (Note: The maximum size of each header name is 40 characters. The header name isn't case sensitive. Wildcards aren't supported.), specify the value (128 characters max) and define an action that points to your desired target group.

Comment: That was my idea. But then what will be the best way to define the different specs of services? One idea is to have different types of EC2 attached to the cluster and somehow route traffic between those. But probably easier it will be to have separate clusters?

Another point is that currently we have nginx in front of our service. Will it be still required when Application Load Balancer will be in use?

Comment: I may not be qualified to identify the "Best" way to define the different specs of services as you will be more knowledgable of what your application needs and the various constraints surrounding it. The'll be multiple approaches but only you guys can tell which approach may benefit your company more.